# GATT over BR/EDR - Bluez

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluez

I want to use bluez with GATT over classic as server and connect to iPhone (apple provides sample code for gatt over BR/EDR). I disabled le (le off).

when using python code I'm able to connect (both from ios settings and get notified by application for connection event) and see services (example-gatt-server). when using the c code (https://github.com/evanslai/bluez-gatt/blob/master/btgatt-server.c) I'm able to connect  from ios settings but i do not receive connection event on application. The application presents the device to connect for a specific service. I currently don't have BR/EDR sniffer. When using GATT over LE I'm able to see the service. **Note**: I do receive a connection event for gatt/gap service. It seems like the heart rate service is not presented in the discovery phase (or any other custom service I tried to add)

Comment: When you say "not from application," how are you connecting from the application? Are you calling `registerForConnectionEvents` (remember, BR/EDR connection is handled through settings, not the app; the app is then notified). Have you studied the WWDC video that covers this? (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901/)

Comment: I do call registerForConnectionEvents. 
when I use the c file I'm not getting connection event when trying to find the heart rate service (i do get a connection event for gatt service). Also I can't see the heart rate service in bluetoothctl when connecting (it should show the services's uuids that the device has - i do see gap/gatt services though)